# How to log the activations of a given layer for later statistics during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am training a model in tf.keras and I want to save all the activations of a given layer during training (so at each batch for instance) in order to be able to track boxplots/histograms of these activations in Tensorboard.

I am getting lost between Tensorboard callbacks options I don't manage to use for this purpose.

I have tried to write custom callback but I get an error when I use `.numpy` on the `model.layers[i].output`.

I have also tried custom metrics but it seems from the example that they only store a variable with `shape=()`.

I have found answer about visualizing activation on inference but not during training on the training data itself.

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to add a histogram summary for activations? Or would you actually like to have a new %step_tensor.npy file stored on each forward path?

Comment: histogram is a good start but I was thinking about other stats like boxplot. Indeed with a binary classifier, I'd like to plot distributions (hist or boxplot) of the output conditionnal on `y_true`